# How to enable and disable yum repos using the command line

Tags: repository, centos7, yum

I'm attempting to edit the `yum.repos.d` file in order to disable unwanted repos and enable wanted repos without using the vi editor. Each time I use the method I know of it fails to make the changes. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

See Below:

```
yum-config-manager --disable \therepoid,anotherrepoid
```

Note: I'm not executing this from the `yum.repos.d` directory

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run the command as `root`
Then you should get the list of repos:

```
yum repolist all
```

And then you can enable or disable particular repo(s) by `repo_id` from previous command

```
yum-config-manager --enable repo_id
```

For reference you can use [RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-managing_yum_repositories)